# Record what user has clicked

Tags: php, mysql, recording

I want to recognize (with php, mysql) and save which blog entries a user has clicked. Like, I have tech entries, lifestyle entries etc. and I want to record which entries a user is interested in, so that I could provide just these entries for him!

So you know what I mean? I wonder if there are any tutorials or something.

Thanks, dartox.

Comment: how about using google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they are opening the page, just store the id of that blog entry in a table. Down the road, you can do something as simple as COUNT (*) on that table for that user, sort by category, and find out what category they're mostly interested in. You can get really complex for recommendations, but this is one of the more simpler ways of accomplishing it. Hope that helps!

Comment: i use this exact methodology for click tracking on advertisements. I track the users IP address, advertisement image id, browser type.. i then run a query `SELECT COUNT(id), COUNT( DISTINCT(IP_ADDRESS) ) FROM advertisements GROUP BY ad_id` and it shows me unique clicks and total clicks grouped by ad_id.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use www.statcounter.com

So create a page: tracker.PHP, and in it put the tracking code from statcounter (or Google analytics for that matter)

On every page with links I'd put a hidden iframe with an id="tracker" and no src just yet, :

```
<iframe id="tracker" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Then every link I'd do something like:

```
<a href="/some_tech_article.php"
 onclick="document.getElementById('tracker').src='/tracker.php?location=techarticle';">Tech Articles
</a>
```

So everytime someone clicks a link, the iframe will invisibly load your tracker.php page and send any information you want to send in the URL (as a [$_GET php variable](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp))....from there you can track and save whatever information you'd like into a database or whatever.

You can use this trick to send information behind the scenes when users click things, without switching pages. I use this to track clicks, and update tables in mysql.

If you need me to give you a better example let me know!